# Java Finalizer method

Tags: java, finalizer

I know that a Java finalize method is invoked by garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object.

Will a Java finalize() method execute after an application exits?

Comment: There's no guarantee that it will be executed even if the JVM shuts down.

Answer (score 5):

> Will a Java finalize() method execute after an application exits?

Normally no.

However, there is a [(deprecated!) method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#runFinalizersOnExit%28boolean%29) that you can call to tell the JVM to finalize objects on JVM exit.  The problem is that it can cause bad things to happen; e.g. erratic behaviour and deadlocks.  So don't use it!

---

In general, it is a bad idea to use `finalize` in application code.  If what you are trying to do here is to implement some shutdown-time behaviour, then a better approach is to implement the behaviour as a shutdown hook.

Answer (score 3):

No.  You can call `Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit()`, but it's deprecated so it may not function.

A workaround would be to create a shutdown hook with `Runtime.addShutdownHook()` and do all your cleanup in the hook.

Answer (score 2):

```
finalize() methods do not run on application exit.
```

The recommended approach is to use a shutdown hook.

e.g.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // shutdown logic
    }
});
```

The shutdown hook is executed when:
  - the program exits normally e.g. System.exit
  - a user interrupt e.g. typing ^C, logoff, or system shutdown

Java also offers a method called, `runFinalizersOnExit()` which was `@deprecated`. It was deprecated for the following reason:

```
It may result in finalizers being called on live objects 
while other threads are concurrently manipulating those objects, 
resulting in erratic behavior or deadlock
```

Essentially, `runFinalizersOnExit()` is unsafe. Use a shutdown hook as I've described above.